# looking to understand meaning of two bytes in HTTP request made with curl --trace

Tags: http, curl, libcurl

tl;dr "What would the bytes `0x33` `0x39` `0x0d` `0x0a` between the end of HTTP headers and the start of HTTP response body refer to?"

I'm using the thoroughly excellent libcurl to make HTTP requests to various 3rd party endpoints. These endpoints are not under my control and are required to implement a specification. To help debug and develop these endpoints I have implemented the text output functionality you might see if you make a curl request from the command line with the -v flag using `curl.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)` and `curl.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, debug_function)`

This has been working great but recently I've come across a request which my debug function does not handle in the same way as curl's debug output. I'm sure is due to me not understanding the HTTP spec.

If making a curl request from the command line with `--verbose` I get the following returned.

```
# redacted headers
< Via: 1.1 vegur
<
{"code":"InvalidCredentials","message":"Bad credentials"}*

Connection #0 to host redacted left intact
```

If making the same request with `--trace` the following is returned

```
0000: 56 69 61 3a 20 31 2e 31 20 76 65 67 75 72 0d 0a Via: 1.1 vegur..
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 0d 0a                                           ..
<= Recv data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: 33                                              3
<= Recv data, 62 bytes (0x3e)
0000: 39 0d 0a 7b 22 63 6f 64 65 22 3a 22 49 6e 76 61 9..{"code":"Inva
0010: 6c 69 64 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 73 22 2c lidCredentials",
0020: 22 6d 65 73 73 61 67 65 22 3a 22 42 61 64 20 63 "message":"Bad c
0030: 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 73 22 7d 0d 0a       redentials"}..
<= Recv data, 1 bytes (0x1)
0000: 30                                              0
<= Recv data, 4 bytes (0x4)
0000: 0d 0a 0d 0a                                     ....
== Info: Connection #0 to host redacted left intact
```

All HTTP client libs I've tested don't include these parts of the bytes in the response body so I'm guessing these are part of the HTTP spec I don't know about but I can't find a reference to them and I don't know how to handle them.

If it's helpful I *think* curl is using this https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/src/tool_cb_dbg.c for building the output in the first example bit I'm not really a c/c++ programmer and I haven't been able to reverse engineer the logic.

Does anyone know what these bytes are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0d 0a` are [ASCII control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters) representing [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_Return) and [line feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Feed), respectively. CRLF is used in HTTP to [mark the end of a header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2) (there are some historic exceptions you should not worry about at this point). A double CRLF is supposed to [mark the end of the fields section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3) of a message.

The `33 39` you observe there is "39" in ascii. This is the [chunk size indicator](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) - treated as a hexdecimal number. The presence of `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` in the response headers may support this.

Comment: Thanks @DaSourcerer. I believe you are correct. The  "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header is present and I don't think it's a coincidence that the 0x39 is 57 in decimal which is the length of the response body. Nice one.

Comment: Oh my. Thanks at @DanielStenberg for correcting me: Yes, the chunk size is indeed ASCII-coded hex. I somehow got stuck in binary.